# What are the design goals of the Solidity Syntax

Tags: solidity

Is it made to be syntactically close to another language?
(Java, JavaScript, JSON).

Is it made to be easy to express contracts?

(Of course there are many restrictions, I am looking for the "goals")

Answer (score 0):

According to Gavin Wood on the cpp-ethereum wiki on August 29th, 2014. Below were the goals

- static typing;
- contracts as first-class entities;
- state as part of a contract able to map & segment information into the storage;
- invariants, pre- and post-conditions as part of a contract;
- variadic return values with named components;
- a safe language subset allowing guaranteed static analysis & proofs;
- an inbuilt test-generation and execution environment for situations where formal proofing is not practical.

[Reference](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gavofyork/31b35cd2252a00d0d057/raw/16de06189d2175d2e31b300f1f8531e20c927635)